# libcurses based audio visualization

Tags: alsa, ncurses

I would like to use a small terminal window to view the histogram of amplitude vs frequency of the current audio output master mix e.g.

[image]

Or (much more) like `htop`'s colored bar graphs.

Comment: OK. So what is your question? Do you want help on writing this or are you looking for an existing tool? If you want an existing tool, what OSes should it run on? Please [edit] and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Google still works:

- https://github.com/dpayne/cli-visualizer
- https://github.com/karlstav/cava

Nine more characters.